# ng-option set default value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble binding my default value to a `ng-option`. I already searched for the answer to my question but can't seem to find one.

My problem is that I have 3 cascading `selects` with one model.

**default values**

```
vm.roomData.branch = 'Lucena';
vm.roomData.building = 'mhq';
vm.roomData.roomFloor = '3rd Floor';
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="branch">
        <strong>Branch</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.branch for loc in vm.locations" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.roomData.branch">
    </select>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Select branch.</small>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="building">
        <strong>Building</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in vm.roomData.branch.building" ng-model="vm.roomData.building" class="form-control">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="roomFloor">
        <strong>Room Floor</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="loc.floors as loc for loc in vm.roomData.building.floors" ng-model="vm.roomData.roomFloor" class="form-control">
    </select>
</div>
```

**vm.locations data**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a681380b7c41e7df2076819",
    "branch": "Lucena",
    "__v": 0,
    "building": [
        {
            "name": "MHQ",
            "floors": [
                "Ground Floor",
                "2nd Floor",
                "3rd Floor"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-24T05:02:56.465Z"
},
{
    "_id": "5a681aecb7c41e7df207681d",
    "branch": "Lucban",
    "__v": 0,
    "building": [
        {
            "name": "MHQ1",
            "floors": [
                "ground floor",
                "2nd floor"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-24T05:34:36.775Z"
}]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what is going on there but you shouldn't expect vm.roomData.branch.building to be anything because branch doesn't have any property called building unless I'm missing something. Also it would be less confusing if you didn't call everything loc.

Comment: @PixMach actually its working problem is that I'm having trouble binding a default value. This is for my edit location page so i really need to bind the default value. I'm sorry that my explanation is like this im not really good at explaining in english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try initializing the default values like this,

```
   $scope.roomData.branch = $scope.locations.find((loc) => loc.branch === 'Lucena'); 
   $scope.roomData.building = $scope.roomData.branch.building.find((br) => br.name.toLowerCase() == 'mhq');
   $scope.roomData.roomFloor = '3rd Floor' ;
```

like

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.roomData = {};
  vm.locations = [{
      "_id": "5a681380b7c41e7df2076819",
      "branch": "Lucena",
      "__v": 0,
      "building": [{
        "name": "MHQ",
        "floors": [
          "Ground Floor",
          "2nd Floor",
          "3rd Floor"
        ]
      }],
      "dateCreated": "2018-01-24T05:02:56.465Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a681aecb7c41e7df207681d",
      "branch": "Lucban",
      "__v": 0,
      "building": [{
        "name": "MHQ1",
        "floors": [
          "ground floor",
          "2nd floor"
        ]
      }],
      "dateCreated": "2018-01-24T05:34:36.775Z"
    }
  ];

  vm.roomData.branch = vm.locations.find((loc) => loc.branch === 'Lucena'); debugger
  vm.roomData.building = vm.roomData.branch.building.find((br) => br.name.toLowerCase() == 'mhq');
  vm.roomData.roomFloor = '3rd Floor' ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl as vm">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="branch">
        <strong>Branch</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.branch for loc in vm.locations" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.roomData.branch">
    </select>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Select branch.</small>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="building">
        <strong>Building</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in vm.roomData.branch.building" ng-model="vm.roomData.building" class="form-control">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="roomFloor">
        <strong>Room Floor</strong>
    </label>
    <select ng-options="o as o for o in vm.roomData.building.floors" ng-model="vm.roomData.roomFloor" class="form-control">
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man.  Can you also make it that if select a branch the building and room floor will remove their value ? cheers thanks again.

Comment: you can use `ng-change` like ` ng-change="vm.roomData.building = ''; vm.roomData.roomFloor = '';"`